# Vue v-for loop click event affecting all items

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've searched and couldn't see any answer that fits what I need. I have a v-for loop  with a button on each item and used VueClipboard2 to copy text. Anytime the button is clicked, I do some css changes to indicated the item that was copied. What happens is that, if there's more than 1 item, clicking on any button affects affect every other item and does the same effect.

I want to limit the clicking to the "own" item being clicked.

Here's my code:

```
<template>
    <div class="form" id="shorten">
        <form class="" @submit.prevent="shortener($event, value)">
            <div>
                <div class="form__shortener">
                    <input
                        class="form-input"
                        type="url"
                        name="link"
                        id="link"
                        placeholder="shorten a url here"
                        aria-label="input a url"
                        v-model="value"
                    />
                    <button class="form-btn btn">
                        {{ buttonText }}
                        <p v-if="loading" class="loading"></p>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <SlideXLeftTransition :delay="100">
                    <p v-if="error" class="error">Please enter a valid link</p>
                </SlideXLeftTransition>
            </div>
        </form>
        <SlideYUpTransition group>
            <div v-for="(link, index) in links" :key="index" class="form__links">
                <p class="form__links-main">
                    {{ link.mainUrl }}
                </p>
                <div class="center form__links-copy">
                    <p>
                        <a :href="link.shortenedUrl" class="form__links-copy-link no-decoration">{{ link.shortenedUrl }}</a>
                    </p>
                    <button
                        class="form__links-copyBtn btn"
                        :class="[copied === true ? 'copied' : '']"
                        v-clipboard:copy="link.shortenedUrl"
                        v-clipboard:success="onCopy"
                        v-clipboard:error="onError"
                    >
                        <span v-if="!loading && !copied">Copy</span>
                        <span v-if="copied">Copied!</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </SlideYUpTransition>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { required, minLength } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators';
import { SlideYUpTransition, SlideXLeftTransition } from 'vue2-transitions';

import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            value: '',
            links: [],
            message: '',
            error: false,
            loading: false,
            buttonText: 'Shorten it!',
            shortenedUrl: '',
            copied: false,
        };
    },
    validations: {
        value: {
            required,
            minLength: minLength(1),
        },
    },
    methods: {
        async shortener(event, value) {
            this.$v.$touch();
            if (this.$v.$invalid) {
                this.showError();
            } else {
                try {
                    this.loading = true;
                    this.buttonText = 'Loading';
                    const request = await axios.post('https://rel.ink/api/links/', { url: value });
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.buttonText = 'Shortened!';
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.buttonText = 'Shorten it!';
                    }, 1200);
                    this.shortenedUrl = `https://rel.ink/${request.data.hashid}`;
                    const mainUrl = request.data.url.length <= 20 ? request.data.url : `${request.data.url.slice(0, 30)}...`;
                    this.links.push({
                        shortenedUrl: `https://rel.ink/${request.data.hashid}`,
                        mainUrl,
                    });
                    localStorage.setItem('links', JSON.stringify(this.links));
                } catch (error) {
                    this.showError();
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
        },
        onCopy() {
            this.copied = true;
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.copied = false;
            }, 2500);
        },
        showError() {
            this.error = true;
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.error = false;
            }, 2000);
        },
        onError() {
            alert('Sorry, there was an error copying that link. please reload!');
        },
        getLinks() {
            if (localStorage.getItem('links')) this.links = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('links'));
        },
    },
    components: {
        SlideYUpTransition,
        SlideXLeftTransition,
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getLinks();
    },
};
</script>
```

I would appreciate if anyone who help out.

Here's the live link: https://url-shortener-vue.netlify.app

To replicate, shorten two lines and click on the copy button on 1. It triggers all other items button.

Thank you.

Comment: changes `copied={}`, then let `this.$set(this.copied, index, true)` when `v-clipboard:success="onCopy(index)"` is triggered. finally change your template like `<span v-if="copied[index]">Copied!</span>`, `:class="[copied[index] ? 'copied' : '']"`

Answer (score -1):

Reason for your problem is
*:class="[copied === true ? 'copied' : '']"*. SInce when you click any copy button, you change copied, and same class is used in all the iterations.

So, got the problem.
Solution is, you should have this **copied** corresponding to each **link**. So make your **link as object**.

```
link = [{ link: 'url...', copied: false}, {}, ...].
```

and, check for each link's copied value.